# How can I sort only the integers in this Javascript array of strings and integers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I need to sort an array of this format, using plain old Javascript or jQuery:

```
var array = [6, 3, 18, 'four', 8, 'five', 6, 'nineteen', 'eight', 'two'];

// Write some javascript or jQuery code below to make sure that
// the integers in the array are correctly ordered from lowest
// to highest.

// Strings should be ignored, remaining in the same order.

// For example, the result for the array above should be:
// [3, 'four', 'five', 6, 6, 8, 18, 'nineteen', 'eight', 'two']

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Why are 'four' and 'five' in the second and third spots?

Comment: why is there a 'two' at the end?

Comment: your example result doesn't match the requirements

Comment: @CanSpice and @Ellipsis...: The strings, 'two', 'four', and 'five' should be ignored.  It probably would have been more clear had I used strings like 'asdf' and 'jkjk'.  The value of the strings is not significant in the scope of the problem- just their order matters.

@Patricia: My example defines the requirements.

Comment: No, my point was that if you're ignoring the non-integers, then why do 'four' and 'five' get moved? Shouldn't the output array be `[3, 6, 6, 'four', 8, 'five', 18, 'nineteen', 'eight', 'two']`?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possible strategies.

Use an array of indices so that you have a layer of indirection -- create an array [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...] and sort that with a custom comparator that dereferences 3 to array[3].  The dereferencing comparator might not obey the transitive property though so you run into undefined behavior.  O(n) extra memory required.

```
var array = [6, 3, 18, 'four', 8, 'five', 6, 'nineteen', 'eight', 'two'];

// Create an array of indices.
var indices = [];
for (var i = array.length; --i >= 0;) { indices[i] = i; }
// indices is [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

// Sort the indices, comparing by number of corresponding element iff
// corresponding elements are both numbers.
indices.sort(function (i, j) {
  var a = array[i], b = array[j];  // dereference
  if (a === (a | 0) && b === (b | 0)) {
    return a === b ? 0 : a < b ? -1 : 1;
  } else {
    return i - j;
  }
});

var newArray = [];
for (var i = array.length; --i >= 0;) { newArray[i] = array[indices[i]; }

array = newArray;
```

The other class of solutions is to extract the numbers, sort, and then replace which requires O(n) extra memory worst-case.

```
var array = [6, 3, 18, 'four', 8, 'five', 6, 'nineteen', 'eight', 'two'];

var integers = array.filter(function (x) { return x === (x | 0); });
integers.sort();

for (var i = 0, k = 0; k < integers.length; ++i) {
  if (array[i] === (array[i] | 0)) { array[i] = integers[k++]; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Mike, but the two options don't quite work.  See the following jsfiddles: http://jsfiddle.net/ericfreese/XjtPY/ and http://jsfiddle.net/ericfreese/kMZ5b/1/

Answer (score 0):

Well, this question was pretty confusing, but after some thought, it seems to me that it's not possible to sort the array the way I was hoping to.

The best solution I came up with is to sort the items as they are added to the list, maintaining a valid array at every step in the process instead of trying to sort after the fact.

Feel free to post other answers.  I'd love to see what people come up with.  It's an interesting problem.